# SQL query to find the first value not used in a column

Tags: mysql

I have a column in a table containing `numbers/ID`s from 0 to 7 not shorted (also no duplicates accepted).

```
Column values 
           7
           1
           2
           6
           5
           0
```

What SQL query do I need to run in order to find the FIRST value not used in this column for the specific table (i.e number 3)?

Answer (score 2):

This might give you what you need

```
SELECT a.id+1 AS `start`
FROM test AS a, test AS b
WHERE a.id < b.id
GROUP BY a.id
HAVING `start` < MIN(b.id)
order by `start` limit 1
```

http://www.codediesel.com/mysql/sequence-gaps-in-mysql/

Comment: Here's one article aswell: http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2005/12/06/find-missing-numbers-in-a-sequence-with-sql/